# Newspaper Usages of "In The Lead"

Tags: phrase-usage, phrasal-verbs, figurative-language

I am so confused about the correctness of the following [usages](http://online.wsj.com/articles/scottish-independence-campaign-takes-lead-according-to-yougov-poll-1410081324) of "in the lead" of a newspaper:

> 1. The U.K. government promised new powers for Scotland if it votes to remain in the U.K. after a weekend opinion poll showed the Scottish independence campaign ***in the lead*** for the first time.
> 2. A poll released late Saturday showed pro-independence voters ***in the lead*** for the first time since the Scottish referendum campaign began.

Are "*the Scottish independence campaign* ***in the lead***" and "*pro-independence voters* ***in the lead***" correct?  It would have made more sense to me if a candidate running for office is "*in the lead*" or a team in some sport is "*in the lead*".

Comment: Yes they are OK. "in the lead" just means ahead of something/someone else. That's all.

Comment: @user3169  But the Scottish independence campaign is not a direct participant in the referendum, so how can it be "*in the lead*"?

Comment: Their campaign is in the lead against the opposition campaign, in order to get their legislation (or such) enacted. The "lead" eventually determines the winner.

Comment: @user3169 But who is the winner?  There is no winner.  A referendum cannot have a winner.  An election could have a winner, because a candidate would get a new job as a result of the election.

Comment: @meatie There is a winner, or a tie. A referendum is a vote by the electorate for a campaign. The term "in the lead" can be used until the final tally reveals the actual winner.

Comment: @user1473511 But the Scottish independence campaign is just a series of activities, not a live person.

Comment: @meatie NO. You are wrong. A campaign is an undertaking, often a military effort, performed by people. In civilized society it can take other forms, such as "a letter writing campaign," or in this case, a referendum to bring about a change in legal status. A "campaign" MAY consist of efforts to elect a candidate, you are quite right, but the word "campaign" is definitely not limited to such usage.

Comment: @user1473511 So, how does a "campaign" become "in the lead"?

Comment: @meatie, by convincing more voters to tell poll-takers that they are likely to vote for its position.

Comment: @ThePhoton Could I then write: "The effort is in the lead."?

Comment: @user3169  Could I then write: "The effort is in the lead."?

Comment: @meatie, if *effort* refers to a group of people working towards a goal in opposition to another group, then yes.

Comment: @ThePhoton  I checked a lot of dictionaries.  "Campaign" is not a group of people.  So to write that "*a campaign is* ***in the lead***" does not make sense.

Comment: @meatie, you are welcome to not use it that way if you prefer not to. You could even write a nasty letter to the newspaper where you saw the text in you question if it makes you feel better. But you probably won't change the way they write.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "in the lead" refers to the comparison of vote tallies of two (or more) campaigns.

A campaign can be run for a person (candidate) seeking office, or for a proposition (bill) to be enacted as law. This referendum refers to the latter.

In this case, the opinions of likely voters are being collected by a pollster interested in predicting the outcome of the referendum vote.

Comment: So, "the Scottish independence campaign ***in the lead***" is poorly written?

Comment: You might add "to be" between "campaign" and "in the lead," but it is not necessary.

Comment: In the context of "showed the… campaign in the lead", the use of a form of "to be" is optional before "in the lead".  If you wanted "The… campaign in the lead" to be a complete sentence, the use of a form of "to be" is required.  An American newspaper would treat "The… campaign" as a singular noun, so it would use the "is" conjugation of "to be".  At the time the article was written, the present tense was appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in that, technically, it is the person or thing *being voted for* that is "in the lead".

However, saying "the campaign" or "the voters" to mean this is not bad writing. It is a case of [metonymy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metonymy) (possibly a [synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche)).

Metonymy is any figure of speech where one thing is referred to using the name of a related thing instead. Synecdoche is the specific case where a part of something is used to name the whole, or *vice versa*.

In this case, "the campaign" and "the voters" are the "related things" being used to name the thing voted for: the decision to become independent (or even the idea of independence).

I say that it might be a synecdoche, because ultimately it's not just "we should become independent" that they're voting on. It's a specific proposal that has been put forward by the politicians and campaigners. Therefore, the words being voted on are *a part of* the whole campaign.